# when I type story in my textbox it should hit this api

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, redux

- when I type story in my textbox it should hit this api
  https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=story
- data should be shown in the browser.
- but right now the call is not happening.
- all the relevant code is in searchbar.js
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-swanson-ioy2u

```or-tag-here
class SearchBar extends Component {
  async searchByKeyword({ target }) {
    await this.getQuery("story", target.value);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getQuery("story", "butts");
  }

  getQuery = async (type = "", search_tag = "") => {
    var url = "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=";
    const resp = await fetch(`${url}${type}&query=${search_tag}`);
    return resp.json();
  };

  render() {
    return <input type="text" onChange={this.searchByKeyword} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: You never setState with the data received or attempt to render any of it

Comment: hey can you update the code in the sandbox, it is so confusing :(

Comment: Am only going off what I see in the question. Haven't even looked at the sandbox. The above code doesn't do anything with the await results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated [your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-lehmann-6z5x5).

Your `searchByKeyword` method wasn't bound to `SearchBar` component which caused `this` to be undefined inside the method. By adding this code is working:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.searchByKeyword = this.searchByKeyword.bind(this);
}
```

On each data fetch your data is sent to `onFetch` prop of `SearchBar` component.
This data is handled by your `App` component:

```
<SearchBar onFetch={this.onFetch} />
```

where data is set to state. That state is represented below search input.